# Mono in linux & windows

Tags: c#, linux, mono

Is there any difference in performance when running two executables with mono in linux, if:

1) the one executable has been compiled from c# source code previously in windows (e.g.VS).

2) the other executable has been compiled from the same source with gmcs in linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't matter from mono runtime's perspective since they are both valid IL codes (assuming compilers are bug-free).

There might be a performance difference which can be attributed to the level of optimization done by the *C# compiler*.

Answer (score 3):

Which compiler on Windows?

I believe gmcs on Windows or Linux will give you the same output.

If you are using a different compiler (e.g. VS / csc) you will probably have subtle differences

Comment: I would like to compare gmcs in linux and VS in windows.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any direct performance difference when running same application on Mono in Linux and Windows. There is an indirect performance difference is possible. By indirect I mean performance difference of mono on Linux and Windows.